# Target XML child elements in XUL document template

Tags: xml, firefox-addon, xul

If I have a simple XML document of

```
<albums>  
  <album name="Napoleon Bonaparte" artist="male" year="1993" genre="rock">  
            <song title="test" track="1"/>
            <song title="test4" track="2"/>
            <song title="test6" track="3"/>
    </album>
  <album name="Cleopatra" artist="female" year="1993" genre="jazz"> 
            <song title="test1" track="1"/>
            <song title="test2" track="2"/>
            <song title="test3" track="3"/>
    </album> 
</albums>
```

And a template that is

```
<box id="albumList" orient="vertical" datasources="list.xml" ref="*" querytype="xml">  
  <template>  
    <query expr="*" />  
    <action>  
        <box uri="?" align="left" class="album"  orient="vertical">  
            <box flex="1">
                <description class="albumName" value="?name"/>  
                <label class="albumArtist" value="?artist"/>
            </box>  
            <listbox class="songlist" align="left" collapsed="true">
                <listitem  uri="?" label="?title"/>
            </listbox>
        </box>
    </action>  
  </template>  
</box>
```

How can I get the `<listbox>` element to properly display the title of each song beneath the album name? The album name/artist display fine, but I can't figure out how to structure the XML query to target the `song` children of `album.`

Comment: Please tell us, how do you want to display the song title and track list? 'cause you are having two columns 1.name 2.artist. 1. The song title will be displayed under the name 2. The track details will be displayed under the artist? Is that you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty tricky question, thank you for asking. [Using recursive templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Template_Guide/Using_Recursive_Templates) documentation provides some clues but seems to be missing an important part. Here is what works in the end:

```
<vbox id="albumList" datasources="list.xml" ref="*" querytype="xml">
  <template>
    <query expr="album|song">
      <assign var="?type" expr="local-name(.)"/>
    </query>
    <rule>
      <where subject="?type" rel="equals" value="album"/>
      <action>
        <vbox uri="?" align="left" class="album">
          <vbox flex="1">
            <description class="albumName" value="?name"/>
            <label class="albumArtist" value="?artist"/>
          </vbox>
          <listbox uri="?" class="songlist" align="left"/>
        </vbox>
      </action>
    </rule>
    <rule parent="listbox">
      <where subject="?type" rel="equals" value="song"/>
      <action>
        <listitem uri="?" label="?title"/>
      </action>
    </rule>
  </template>
</vbox>
```

As suggested by the documentation, this assigns the XML tag name to the `?type` variable and uses it to generate different content for `album` and `song` tags (via `<rule>` and `<where>`). Note `uri="?"` on the `<listbox>` tag, it designates that tag as the point where the generated content for the child tags need to be inserted. But the template engine will additionally insert content for the child tags directly into the content of the parent tag - this is prevented by the `parent="listbox"` restriction on the rule for songs. I changed the query expression to `album|song` to make sure that other tags are immediately ignored but this is not strictly necessary.

A side-note: normally the `<box>` tag isn't used. The `<hbox>` and `<vbox>` tags are preferred since they don't require you to specify content orientation separately.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much for that answer. I couldn't believe there weren't more examples in the documentation as I couldn't wrap my head around the difference between `<query>` and `<rules>`, among other things.